# why the exception (SecurityException:Permisssion Denial)arises on the following code

Tags: android

```
package com.xyz.tryit;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.database.Cursor;
//import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
//import android.provider.Contacts.People;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.PhoneLookup;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;


public class myActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private Button start;
    private malay Malay;

    class malay implements OnClickListener{

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            System.out.print("hiiiiiiii");
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            /*String[] projection=new String[]{
                    People._ID,People._COUNT,People.NAME,People.NUMBER
            };
            Uri contacts=People.CONTENT_URI;

            Cursor managedCursor=managedQuery(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,projection,null,null,People.NAME+"ASC");

            */
            readData();




        }

        public void readData(){
            Cursor people = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

            while(people.moveToNext()) {
               int nameFieldColumnIndex = people.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME);
               String contact = people.getString(nameFieldColumnIndex);
               int numberFieldColumnIndex = people.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.NUMBER);
               String number = people.getString(numberFieldColumnIndex);

               System.out.println("NAME====="+contact+"   NUMBER======="+number);
            }

            people.close();

        }

    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Malay=new malay();
        this.start=(Button)this.findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        System.out.print("hellllllllloooooooooo");
        start.setOnClickListener(Malay);

    }
}
```

Comment: when does the Exception exactly occur? OnClick? OnCreate?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read the FAQ on how to ask a good question. You will see that posting code only isn't a valid question and might be ignored here. The last tip for you: The exception points mostly in the right direction. Just read it as a plain English phrase...

Answer (score 1):

Did you request the [READ_CONTACTS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_CONTACTS) permission
in AndroidManifest.xml?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
```

Comment: I got the following error with that permission--------------01-02 05:05:09.144: ERROR/CursorWindow(11101): Bad request for field slot 0,-1. numRows = 2, numColumns = 17

Comment: Sorry, don't know about that one. Your original issue seems to be solved though?